# Redirecting stdout/stderr to multiple files

Tags: bash, unix, stdout, stderr

I was wondering how to redirect stderr to multiple outputs. I tried it with this script, but I couldn't get it to work quite right. The first file should have both stdout and stderr, and the 2nd should just have errors.

```
perl script.pl &> errorTestnormal.out &2> errorTest.out
```

Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hover on the tags you have added, followers for stdout/stderr = 7 total. You'll get more eyes on your problem if you include a tag for the shell you are using, bash, I assume? Good luck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The command below will do what you want.

```bash
perl script.pl 2>&1 >errorTestnormal.out | tee -a errorTestnormal.out > errorTest.out`
```

This is a bit messy, so lets go through it step by step.

- We say what used to go to `STDERR` will now go `STDOUT`.
- We say what used to go to `STDOUT` will now go to `errorTestnormal.out`.

So now, `STDOUT` gets printed to a file, and `STDERR` gets printed to `STDOUT`. We want put `STDERR` into 2 different files, which we can do with tee. tee appends the text it's given to a file, and also echoes to `STDOUT`.

- We use `tee` to append to `errorTestnormal.out`, so it now contains all the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` output of `script.pl`.
- Then, we write `STDOUT` of `tee` (which contains `STDERR` from `script.pl`) into `errorTest.out`

After this, `errorTestnormal.out` has all the `STDOUT` output, and then all the `STDERR` output. `errotTest.out` contains only the `STDERR` output.

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman. Fantastic answer, and many thanks :)

Comment: There is no need to use fd 3.  You can simply do: perl script.pl 2>&1 >errorTestnormal.out | tee ...   The first redirection associates fd 2 (stderr) with the pipe, and the second redirects stdout to the file.  If you do: perl script.pl > errorTestnormal.out 2>&1, then both stderr and stdout go to the file.

Answer (score 3):

I had to mess around with this for a while as well. In order to get stderr in both files, while only putting stdout into a single file (e.g. stderr into errors.log and output.log and then stdout into just output.log) AND in the order that they happen, this command is better:

```
((sh test.sh 2>&1 1>&3 | tee errors.log) 3>&1 | tee output.log) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The last /dev/nul 2>&1 can be omitted if you want the stdout and stderr to still be output onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in case of the 2nd ">" you try to send the error output of `errorTestnormal.out` (and not that of `script.pl`) to `errorTest.out`.